# How can append a list arising from split of a string to a csv using column identifiers?

Tags: python, loops, split

I am writing a flask app to ingest a string being received via a Webhook every few minutes. My plan is to split the string and then loop over the string to extract individual variables which I will then append to a csv which will grow over time. How can I best to define the first part of the created list as the column header and second part of the string as the relevant value?

```py
# The string received through the WebHook
string = 'https://example.com/test?Date_Event=2013-12-31T15:21:32Z&DeviceID=Item1&Variable=11.1'
# Removing the URL as not used 
string1 = string.replace("https://example.com/test?","")
# Splitting the remaining string by the '&' character
res = string1.split('&')
# Loop through the remaining string to pull out column names and values
for x in res:
    datapoint = x.split('=')
    print(datapoint)
```

```
Example output:
['Date_Event', '2013-12-31T15:21:32Z']
['DeviceID', 'Item1']
['Variable', '11.1']
```

The output I am hoping for is:

```
Date_Event           | DeviceID | Variable
------------------------------------------
2013-12-31T15:21:32Z | Item1    | 11.1
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use pandas? Are you trying to create a dataframe?

Comment: Great idea @AndrejKesely - I had wondered if writing directly to a csv might be more efficient than to a df then csv, however, happy to go via a df.